# tuple index out of range in dfs

Tags: python, indexing, tuples, range, depth-first-search

This is my code:

```
class solution:
    lot = [[1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,9,1]]   
    def move(lot):
        if lot is None:
            return -1
        if (len(lot) <= 0 or len(lot[0]) <= 0):
            return -1
        q = []
        visited = [len(lot)], [len(lot[0])]
        direction= [(0,1), (0,-1), (1,0), (-1,0)]
        q.append((0,0))
        result = 0
        
        while (len(q) > 0):
            size = len(q)
            for i in range(size):
                node= q.pop(0)
                x = node[0]
                y = node[1]
                visited[x][y]= True
                if(lot[x][y] == 9):
                    return result
                for dir in direction:
                    nx = x+ dir[0]
                    ny = y + dir[1]
                    r= len(lot[nx])
                    
                    
                    if (nx < 0 or nx >= len(lot) or ny < 0 or ny > r or lot[nx][ny] == 0 or visited[nx][ny] == True):
                        continue
                    q.append((nx,ny))
                
            result += result
        return result
    print(move(lot))
```

It generates the following error:

```
File "prog.py", line 29, in move
    if (nx < 0 or nx >= len(lot) or ny < 0 or ny > r or lot[nx][ny] == 0 or visited[nx][ny] == True):
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: Demolition Robot
Given a matrix with values 0 (trenches) , 1 (flat) , and 9 (obstacle) you have to find minimum distance to reach 9 (obstacle). If not possible then return -1.
The demolition robot must start at the top left corner of the matrix, which is always flat, and can move on block up, down, right, left.
The demolition robot cannot enter 0 trenches and cannot leave the matrix.
Sample Input :
[1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0],
[1, 9, 1]]
Sample Output :
3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because of your `visited` variable. You're trying to access `visited[nx][ny]` which doesn't exist.
Separately, your DFS algorithm is incorrect. See [here](http://bryukh.com/labyrinth-algorithms/) for how to implement DFS correctly.

Your function should be like this:

```
def move(lot):
    if lot is None:
        return -1
    if (len(lot) <= 0 or len(lot[0]) <= 0):
        return -1
    
    q = []
    visited = set()
    q.append((0,0))
    result = 0
    
    while len(q)>0:
        x,y = q.pop(0)
        if(lot[x][y]==9):
            return result
        if (x,y) in visited:
            continue
        visited.add((x,y))
        for d in [(0,1), (0,-1), (1,0), (-1,0)]:
            nx = x + d[0]
            ny = y + d[1]
            if (nx<0 or nx>=len(lot) or ny<0 or ny>len(lot[0]) or lot[nx][ny]==0 or (nx,ny) in visited):
                continue
            q.append((nx,ny))       
            result += 1
    return result
```